CMakeLists Causing "The code execution cannot proceed because SDL3.dll was not found" Linking Error
I would like to include Dear Imgui in my CMake project with an SDL3 backend. I would like to build a static library of SDL3 that gets linked to my application.
Here is the current directory structure for my CMake project:
app/
├─ include/
│  ├─ app.h
├─ vendor/
│  ├─ SDL/
│  │  ├─ CMakeLists.txt
│  ├─ imgui/
├─ source/
│  ├─ app.cpp
CMakeLists.txt

Here is my current CMakeLists.txt file:
# CMakeList.txt : CMake project for app, include source and define
# project specific logic here.
#
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.12)

project ("app")

# Define include directories
set(APP_INCLUDE_DIRS
    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/include"
)

set(IMGUI_INCLUDE_DIRS
    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/imgui"
    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/imgui/backends"
)

# Define source files
set(APP_SOURCES
    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/source/main.cpp"
)

set(IMGUI_SOURCES
    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/imgui/imgui.cpp"
    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/imgui/imgui_demo.cpp"
    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/imgui/imgui_draw.cpp"
    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/imgui/imgui_tables.cpp"
    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/imgui/imgui_widgets.cpp"
    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/imgui/backends/imgui_impl_sdl3.cpp"
    "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/imgui/backends/imgui_impl_opengl3.cpp"
)

# Add libs
set(SDL_ROOT "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/lib/SDL")
add_subdirectory("${SDL_ROOT}" EXCLUDE_FROM_ALL)
find_package(OpenGL REQUIRED)

# Include directories
include_directories(${APP_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${IMGUI_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIRS})

# Add source to this project's executable.
add_executable (app ${APP_SOURCES} ${IMGUI_SOURCES})

# Add target libaries
target_link_libraries(app PRIVATE SDL3::SDL3 ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})

With the current version of my CMakeLists.txt file. When I run my application I get the following error: "The code execution cannot proceed because SDL3.dll was not found". I can see that the dll is being generated in build folder and is not being linked. Regardless this is dynamic linking and I would like to use static linking.
If I try replace line:
target_link_libraries(app PRIVATE SDL3::SDL3 ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})

with the static linking target:
target_link_libraries(app PRIVATE SDL3::SDL3-static ${OPENGL_LIBRARIES})

I get a CMake error saying the target is not found. Any ideas how I can fix this?

For build static version of SDL3 you need to enable SDL_STATIC option: https://github.com/libsdl-org/SDL/blob/main/docs/README-cmake.md#sdl-specific-cmake-options. E.g you could add the line set(SDL_STATIC ON CACHE INTERNAL "") before add_subdirectory("${SDL_ROOT}").

I adding "set(SDL_STATIC ON CACHE INTERNAL "")" caused some errors but I tried "set(SDL_STATIC ON)" and that worked perfectly. Any idea why my previous setup was causing that dll issue?

For locate a .dll library at runtime, the directory with the library should be added to the PATH or the library itself should be copied near the executable which uses that library.

I get a CMake error saying the target is not found. Maybe that means the SDL you have does not contain static libraries. Remember that .lib files can also be import libraries which require the .dll
